# Kendo ui detail init and child grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I´m struggling with this for a few hours, and i know it´s a rookie question but i´m really stuck on this one and i was hopping someone could point me in the right direction.

I´m using the Kendo ui [detail template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate) and just want to access the child grid to customize it (css) but i don´t know how to access it. I have seen some examples that only take me to this:

```
dataBound: function() 
          {
            var dataSource = this.dataSource;         
            this.element.find('tr.k-master-row').each(function() 
            {
               var row = $(this);         
               var data = dataSource.getByUid(row.data('uid'));
               row.find('.k-hierarchy-cell').css({ opacity: 0.3, cursor: 'default' });


            });
          },
```

But as some of you may know, this is for the button that expands the master row and then shows the child grid. Actually it has nothing to do with what i want.

```
function detailInit(e) 
{

 e.detailRow.find(".k-detail-cell > div.k-grid.k-widget").css("background-color", "yellow");
 console.log(e.detailRow[0]);

 $('<div id="childGrid"> <div/>').appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
 "rest of the code not relevant"
```

I have used a console.log to see inside the detail row and do..."something" but i don´t know how...

Comment: Something like this: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uTolO ? It is not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Thanks for helping me, that´s what i wanted, meanwhile i have discouvered it´s this: $('.k-detail-row').find('.k-detail-cell').children('#childGrid').children('.k-header.k-grid-toolbar')
                .children(".k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-close").css('display','none');